# Pipe Separting inline in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am havin following data when execute my query

[image]

I also have function which will pipe seprate Colum ReportType but it is writtening me column

I want result in following format

```
ItemID |ReportType|EmailAddrress |FirstName|LastName
1      |        1  |abc@gmail.com| test    |test 
1      |        2  |abc@gmail.com| test1   |test1
```

My SQL function seems to be of no use

My function is

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = '|' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
```

select is normal query

SELECT ItemId, ReportType, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName
FROM EmailInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly then i think this is what you want to achieve.

```
SELECT ItemId, col.item AS ReportType, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName
FROM EmailInfo
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplit(ReportType, '|') col
```

Comment: I think that should be `col.item as ReportType`, but this seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @PushkarPhule: Glad to help you.